# Album -art display

Tags: qt

How to display album art / cover art in Qt?

Comment: I little bit more information would be nice. Do you develope an own media player? Do you use Phonon? Are you just taking mp3 files as input and want to get the album art from the meta info?

Comment: Yes i am developing my own player for streaming audio/video data and i am using phonon. I am unable to display any cover-art. So i needed information on whether phonon supports it or i need to add some other module for image display

Comment: AFAIK, Phonon does not support the extraction of album art. I found a perl script which does this job and saves album art from mp3 in jpeg-files. Don't know if that can help you. http://www.galwayland.com/?page_id=128